# MVC Design Question

Tags: model-view-controller, session, variables

**On a MVC 2 website** what I want to do is get a list of products / CategoryId.  From that list, create a list of   distinct CategoryId's.  Then randomly pick a categoryId from the second list and use it to get all the products for that categoryId.  I then want to store that CategoryId so that I don't display those products on the next run.

I don't need any code examples to start.  What I'm wondering is that I think I would put this code in a class in my model (Dll) and store the list of displayed CategoryId's in session.  Is this a good solution or should I go another way?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could all belong to your Product model, using methods like getAllProductsByCategoryId(id) and maybe use a Category model to do the reverse.

Comment: So would it be okay to store the list of displayed categoryId's in session?

Comment: First of, thanks dhdean and Tilo for your answers.  I have one more question.  In my domain model (dll) I have and IQueryable<T> function where I would be putting this code.  How do I either pass a Session var into this function or use the HttpSessionStateWrapper or Base to get and store Session data?  Thanks again